# using .bashrc to keep X11 forwarding

Tags: bash, x11, sudo

When I switch to root (sudo su), I first have to run `xauth list` as myself then `xauth add <last entry from xauth list>` once I'm root. I found a great little tip to make this easier by running `xauth add $(xauth -f ~<my username>/.Xauthority list|tail -1)`. This is nice, but I wanted to automate it.

So, I went into /root/.bashrc and added this:
`xauth add $(xauth -f ~$SUDO_USER/.Xauthority list|tail -1)`

Unfortunately, that gives the error `error in locking authority file ~<my user>/.Xauthority`

It works if I just replace $SUDO_USER with my username. Clearly $SUDO_USER is set correctly because it knows to look for the correct authority file. So, what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` [expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) is done before variable interpolation. If you do a strace, you will see that the actual error is `No such file or directory`

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "~<myuser>/.Xauthority-c", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "xauth:  error in locking authori"..., 62xauth:  error in locking authority file ~<myuser>/.Xauthority
```

use `/home/$SUDO_USER/.Xauthority` instead

Answer (score 0):

The real trick is to use `eval` to get a second round of expansion.

Consider:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ~$SUDO_USER
eval echo ~$SUDO_USER

a="~$SUDO_USER"
eval b="~$SUDO_USER"

echo a = "$a"
echo b = "$b"
```

The first `echo`s show that you can do it on a normal command, though I don't advise it.

The assignments are probably a safer way to go, as you can control exact what gets evaluated twice.

In case you are wondering, my sample executions read:

```
$ env SUDO_USER=n1 ./sample_script
~n1
/home/n1
a = ~n1
b = /home/n1
$ env SUDO_USER=gnats ./sample_script
~gnats
/var/lib/gnats
a = ~gnats
b = /var/lib/gnats
$
```

As you can see, this also avoids assuming all home directories are in a particular directory.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in two separate successive statements to avoid this locking, example:

```
xauthval=$(xauth -f ~YOUR_USER_NAME/.Xauthority list|tail -1)
(( $? == 0 )) && xauth add ${xauthval}
```

For security reasons, you might not want to do this on a production system.

Comment: I tried a couple things along those lines but it didn't help. I don't want to put my username in there I want to use the SUDO_USER variable. It's not a production system. This is purely for use in a dev environment.